Differences between each group
I have a dataframe like this:
df = data.frame(
  repetition = c(1,1,1,2,2,2),
  group = c("a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "c"),
  res = c(10,8,9,12,9,10)
)

  repetition group res
1          1     a  10
2          1     b   8
3          1     c   9
4          2     a  12
5          2     b   9
6          2     c  10

Now, for each repetition, I want to compute the differences (in res) for each group. So the differences between group a and b, a and c and b and c. However, this could potentially be many more groups.
I would like to have an output like this:
  repetition diff_a_b diff_a_c diff_b_c
1          1        2        1       -1
2          2        3        2       -1

I would like to have columns like diff_a_b, diff_a_c. Is there a way in dplyr (or also any other) on how to do that?

We can split by repetition then run diff on all combnations.
> t(sapply(split(df$res, df$repetition), \(x) -combn(x, 2, FUN=diff)))
  [,1] [,2] [,3]
1    2    1   -1
2    3    2   -1

Just some cosmetics:
> data.frame(repetition=unique(df$repetition),
+            `colnames<-`(t(sapply(split(df$res, df$repetition), \(x) -combn(x, 2, FUN=diff))),
+                         paste0('diff_', combn(unique(df$group), 2, paste, collapse='_'))))
  repetition diff_a_b diff_a_c diff_b_c
1          1        2        1       -1
2          2        3        2       -1


Data:
> dput(df)
structure(list(repetition = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2), group = c("a", 
"b", "c", "a", "b", "c"), res = c(10, 8, 9, 12, 9, 10)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))


oh cool!:) What does the colnames<--Assignment do directly?

@Lenn It dynamically sets the column names got from the second combn. It's similar to setNames, just for matrices. t throws a matrix.

Probably you can try
df %>%
    summarise(diff = list(setNames(
        as.data.frame(t(-combn(res, 2, diff))),
        paste0("diff_", combn(group, 2, paste0, collapse = "_"))
    )), .by = repetition) %>%
    unnest(diff)

which gives
# A tibble: 2 × 4
  repetition diff_a_b diff_a_c diff_b_c
       <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
1          1        2        1       -1
2          2        3        2       -1


Thanks again @ThomasIsCoding! I just have a quick question. By also unsing combn in setting the names. Is it assured that the names always match the real differences?

@Lenn yes, you are right

Thanks! So the combinations always match?

@Lenn yes, always matches

An approach using outer
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  reframe(value = outer(res, res, "-")[upper.tri(diag(n()))], 
          name  = outer(group, group, paste, sep="_")[upper.tri(diag(n()))],
    .by = repetition) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_prefix="diff_")
# A tibble: 2 × 4
  repetition diff_a_b diff_a_c diff_b_c
       <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
1          1        2        1       -1
2          2        3        2       -1

